# Is the phrase "flesh split" a tautology(needless repetition of the same thing)?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

This is an article from Wikipedia about Chamois Leather.

> Chamois leather is a type of porous leather, traditionally the skin of the chamois (Rupicapra rupicapra), a type of European mountain goat, but today made almost exclusively from the **flesh split** of a sheepskin.

TFD def of the word "flesh":
11. (Tanning) (modifier) tanning of or relating to the **inner or under layer** of a skin or hide: a flesh split.

TFD def of the word "split":
a. a separated layer of an animal hide or skin **other than the outer layer**

The bold part is the reason I'm making this post. If the word "flesh" means related to to inner part of a sking and the word "split" means layer of skin other than outer layer-which basically means any inner layer of skin, isn't the phrase "flesh split" used in Wikipedia a tautology(needless repetition of the same thing)? I know I might be hairsplitting a lot because I know the meaning of the phrase and what it means.

Comment: You have the definition, so what is the problem??

Comment: @gotube: Done (with some rewording). So the remaining comments here are redundant.

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily.

The sense of "split" used in this definition is very technical.  Certainly I did not know this sense of the word. It is apparent that several splits can be taken from a single hide, so a "split" might be from the bottom layer of the hide, or from a middle layer. Technically, it isn't the top layer.

Moreover, this technical sense conflicts with the usual meaning of "split" meaning "A piece that is split off".  In this non-technical sense it would seem that the top layer of the hide could be called a "split".  Only someone with knowledge of the technical term could know that it is not.  So to help general readers, it is good to add a little redundancy, to clarify the sense of a technical term.

For example:  "The operators ran the computer program on the Mark 1."  Now in the context a "program" is a "sequence of instructions for a computer", so "computer program" is pleonastic.  However for non-technical people who don't know the technical meaning of "program", the compound noun helps understanding. There's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

In the cited context, the noun ***split*** effectively means a ***layer** [created by splitting something thicker into two or more thinner sheets].* The same sense applies in mining - if a parting in a coal seam becomes so thick that the two portions of the seam must be worked separately, each "layer" is called a split. Or in AmE, it can mean *a piece of wood separated or formed by splitting* (in BrE, a ***splint***).

In principle, the soft inner (flesh side) layer and the tough outer (hair side) layer are both "split" from the full hide, so ***flesh split*** usefully clarifies which layer we're talking about.

It's true the Free Dictionary explicitly provides a definition of ***split*** as the *inner* layer of a split hide. But the full Oxford English Dictionary doesn't give that sense (which is essentially dialectal / domain-specific anyway).

IMHO, it doesn't count as "tautology" if 99% of native speakers wouldn't get the intended meaning just from the bare word ***split***. And even if a usage *was* tautologous / redundant for most native speakers (which definitely doesn't apply to OP's example), this wouldn't imply there's anything *wrong* with it. Tautology is a natural feature of English in many contexts.